# StepDefinitions.java file is not picked up by TestRunner of my Serenity maven running

Tags: serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

I kept my **(prefix_name)Runner.java** file under _ __src/test/java/(company_domain_package)\runner** _ folder and
kept my _**(prefix_name)StepDefinitions.java**_ file under **src/test/java/(company_domain_package)\stepdefinitions**  folder.

In my Eclipse when I run mvn clean verify, I am only seeing this comment.

"You can implement missing steps with the snippets below:"

and the accompanying empty stub methods automatically generated by Cucumber in the Eclipse console window, instead of running the **src/test/java/(company_domain_package)\stepdefinitions\prefix_nameStepDefinitions.java** file.

I mentioned in my @CucumberOptions the complete path of feature file (obviously it is being picked up, because the **@Given, @When, @Then** stub methods are being output in console.

Even though I implemented the @Given Step in my **prefixStep.java** file which uses **(prefix)Page.java** to do low level Selenium calls.

**What is the omission I am doing ?**

I kept my **(prefix_name)Runner.java** file under **src/test/java/(company_domain_package)\runner>** folder and
kept my **(prefix_name)StepDefinitions.java** file under **src/test/java/(company_domain_package\stepdefinitions)** folder.

In my Eclipse when I run "mvn clean verify", I am only seeing this comment
"You can implement missing steps with the snippets below:"
 and the accompanying empty stub methods automatically generated by Cucumber in the Eclipse console window, instead of running the **src/test/java/(company_domain_package\stepdefinitions)(prefix_name)StepDefinitions.java* file.

I mentioned in my **@CucumberOptions** the complete path of feature file (obviously it is being picked up, because the **@Given, @When, @Then** stub methods are being output in console.

```
 public class PramaDatahubPageStep {
 DataHubPage dataHubPage;

   @Step
public boolean loginPramaDatahubSite(String uId, String 
                                              passCode) {
    boolean isVerified = false;
    configureChromeDriver();// private method
            setChromeDriver(); // private method
    dataHubPage.open();
    dataHubPage.login( uId, passCode);
    isVerified = dataHubPage.verifyLogin();
    return isVerified;
}


@DefaultUrl("https://prama-stg.xxxxx.com/datahub")
  public class DataHubPage extends PageObject {
 @FindBy(id = "loginButton")
private WebElementFacade loginButton;

@FindBy(id = "errorDiv") 
private WebElementFacade loginError;

@FindBy(id = "password")
private WebElementFacade password;

@FindBy(id = "eID")
private WebElementFacade userId;

public void login(String uId, String passCode){
    userId.sendKeys(uId);
    password.sendKeys(passCode);
    loginButton.click();
}
```

I am expecting my StepDifinitions.java file to be run and the web site opened and logged in with the data table provided in the feature file.

Comment: Looks like I found where is my problem, even though I don't know why !
Whether it is 
src/main/java .   OR
src/test/java .     OR
src/test/resources  which are pre-existing folders in a maven project, the Serenity is NOT liking to have a company domain package to be put beneath them. When you keep your Java files, whether it is a cucumber Runner file, or stepDefinitions file or step file, no matter it is NOT able or NOT like to see them. 
</br>
When I removed the company domain package and moved the java files directly up to the default folders, it works.

Comment: Can some one explain why ?
Technically it should read java files until they are on the class path . Right ?

Comment: I think, I solved this issue, by adjusting the options like
- features
- glue
etc., parameters.
More over some times dependencies in your pom file also have some affect, I suppose.

Comment: features - glue etc., parameters in the Runner java file